# vector clip based on chronological value

Tags: python, clip

I would like to know if there is any algorithm in python that can clip  vector features according to the "date" value?
To be more specific the newest date is the dominant value and clipping will start from it

Answer (score 1):

From what i understad, you want to clip / select all features depending on a date?
If this is the case you can use the python module : shapely or ogr2ogr.

You can have a look at this link : [code examples, ...](http://www.macwright.org/2012/10/31/gis-with-python-shapely-fiona.html)

Comment: see this thread also :http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91676/select-by-attributes-within-the-fiona-python-module