# Select by attribute using fiona

Tags: python, gdal, fiona

```
    with fiona.open(constants.file_combined, 'r') as source:
        filtered = filter(lambda f: f['properties']['NAME'] == name_dm1, source)

        # **source.meta is a shortcut to get the crs, driver, and schema
        # keyword arguments from the source Collection.
        with fiona.open(out_dir + os.sep + name_dm1 + '.shp', 'w', **source.meta) as sink:
            for feature in filtered:
                try:
                    sink.write(feature)
                except Exception, e:
                    # Writing uncleanable features to a different shapefile
                    # is another option.
                    print out_dir + os.sep + name_dm1 + '.shp'
```

I have a shapefile from which I want to select based on presence of certain values in a column called 'NAME'.

However, in the code above, it creates a shapefile with an empty attribute table even though I am sure there is data in the original shapefile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much more easily:

```
with fiona.open("a_shapefile.shp") as input:
    meta = input.meta
    with fiona.open('a_shapefile2.shp', 'w',**meta) as output:
        for feature in input:
             if feature['properties']['NAME']== name_dm1:
                 output.write(feature)
```

Comment: Might be nice to use filter() as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91676/select-by-attributes-within-the-fiona-python-module / http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html#slicing-and-masking-iterators