# Difference in geometries of shapefiles

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, fiona, differences

I have the geometry of the outline region as part of one shapefile (which is only one feature and there are other features in it apart from this). Other polygon regions' boundaries which are colored are present in another shapefile.

Is there a way to find out the geometry of non-coloured regions (altogether as one polygon or multiple polygons) of the image?

I tried with the code below but it was giving me the geometry of the entire region.

[image]

```py
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping, Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona

schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'test': 'float'}}

outline_shape = fiona.open(shapefile1)
region_shape = fiona.open(shapefile2)

for feature in outline_shape:
    if feature['properties']['Name'] == 'Required field':
        schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': {'test': 'int'}}
        with fiona.open('diff.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
            for geom in [shape(feature['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])) for j in region_shape]:
                if not geom.is_empty:
                    e.write({'geometry': mapping(geom), 'properties': {'test': 1}})
```

Comment: You mean you want the areal geometry that is inside the thick black line but not covered by the regions marked in yellow?

Comment: Yeah, I want the regions inside which aren’t coloured In yellow

Answer (score 1):

This is completely untested but should do the trick.

The idea is to make a Polygon from the outline so that you can actually compute areal differences. For the regions I made a single geometry so the code does not have to recompute differences again and again, this should be faster.

I also changed your file handling to best practises with `with` contexts. And I added some assertions to catch misunderstandings.

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping, Polygon
from shapely.ops import unary_union


# load all regions and make a single geometry of them
with fiona.open(regions_file) as regions:
    regions_geometries = [shape(f["geometry"]) for f in regions]
    regions_geometry = unary_union(regions_geometries)

# load the wanted outline
# via https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91676/select-by-attributes-within-the-fiona-python-module
with fiona.open(outlines_file) as outlines:
    filtered = filter(lambda f: f["properties"]["Name"] == "Required field", outlines)
    assert len(filtered) == 1, "more than 1 match?"
    outline = filtered[0]

outline_geometry = shape(outline["geometry"])

# assuming you actually have an outLINE (as LineString)
outline_geometry = Polygon(outline_geometry)

# compute the difference
difference_geometry = outline_geometry.difference(regions_geometry)
assert not difference_geometry.is_empty, "no remaining difference geometry?"

# ready to write to output
schema = {"geometry": "Polygon", "properties": {"test": "int"}}

difference_feature = {
    "geometry": mapping(difference_geometry),
    "properties": {"test": 1},
}

with fiona.open("diff.shp", "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema) as output:
    output.write(difference_feature)
```

You might be missing a CRS for the output but that is up to you :)

Comment: I tried with the above code but the resultant is the outline geometry.

Comment: Does your regions file include all regions or just the yellow ones?

Comment: It has only yellow ones.

Comment: Do they both have the same CRS?

Comment: Yes both of them are in same CRS, but region shapefile has 3D geometry whereas outline shapefile is 2D file

Comment: That should not matter. I am lost why this does not work then, sorry.